# Wpf Tooltip Object reference error

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling, tooltip

I am trying to set a tooltip to a textbox progamatically,but i  keep getting the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   e-Learning.exe but was not handled in user code The error :Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.

the code:

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.Content="Introduceti adresa URL a videocipului";
loca.ToolTip = tt;
```

any ideas how can i set the tooltip ?
I am sorry if i wasn't clearly enough.
P.S "loca" is the name of the textbox

Comment: Related: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yes loca is null how can i change it ?

Comment: loca is a textbox.i am reading it right now

Comment: Can you post some more code? Like your `xaml` where you have added that `TextBox` "loca" and `ViewModel`/Code behind where you are instantiating or accessing that `TextBox`.

Comment: here is the xaml of the textbox
 <TextBox x:Name="loca" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" Margin="305,91,0,0" MaxLines="1" ToolTip=""/>

and that is the code i wrote in the .cs file,it is triggered by chosing a radio button.

As grant winney said, loca is null,but i dont know how i can istantiate it,
and i am new to wpf(&still learning c#)